# Android: JSON isn't working, Log.e returns a null

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get the USD average price 30d for bitcoins from here: http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/weighted_prices.json. The Json code I have does not work in the try/catch, and the error is a null (I have tried looking into other questions but all of them seem to return errors, whereas mine just returns a null):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dogewidget);
            TextView btctest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

            //Create a new HTTP Client
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //Setup the get request
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/weighted_prices.json");
            //Depending on web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                result = reader.readLine();

                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject jsubObject = jObject.getJSONObject("USD");
                String btcjson = jsubObject.getString("30d");
                btctest.setText(btcjson);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("error", "" + e.getMessage());
                btctest.setText("Error " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception squish) {
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What does a "null" mean? Does that mean a NullPointerException? If so you need to post the stack trace.

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` to do your web call

Comment: I may be wrong but I seem to remember if you call `e.printStackTrace()` it will clear the message. That means when you try to use `Log.e(...)` in your code with `e.getMessage()` it will simply return "null" as the message string. There's no point in using `Log.e(...)` at this point anyway as `e.printStackTrace()` will dump the whole of the exception stack trace including the message and cause.

Comment: I can't edit my comment after 5 minutes but as @SathishKumar says, you should be using an `AsyncTask` or similar to perform network operations. The exception you're getting is probably telling you that you shouldn't perform network operations on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: I just got it to work thanks to @SathishKumar's suggestion to do AsyncTask. Thanks all! It was giving a null when I was trying to find the error, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
private void get_value(String php) {
 String responseString = null;
 try{    
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  String url ="your_url"; 
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
  out.close();
  responseString = out.toString();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),responseString,1000).show();

  //The below code is for Separating values.It may varies according with your result

  JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(responseString);
  int x=Integer.parseInt(ja.getJSONObject(0).getString("your_string_name"));

} catch(Exception e) {
}
}
```